# Bootstrap inline two divs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How would I inline the following blog post example. I want the tag to appear inline to the title, here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rmhq8/

```
<div class="blog-title" >Title test #1</div>
<div class="blog-tag" >
    <span class="label label-warning ">Event</span></div>
<div class="blog-author">Author: Jareddlc</div>
<div class="blog-date">posted: Wednesday, June 12, 2013 7:11:00 PM</div>
<pre>Testing text that goes inside the body</pre>
<div class="blog-program">tag: ENG</div>
<hr style="border-top: 1px dotted #b0b0b0;border-bottom: 0px">
```

I am building that dynamicaly with jquery:

```
var title = "<div class=\"blog-title\" >"+post.title+"</div>";
var tag = "<div class=\"blog-tag\" ><span class=\"label label-warning \">"+post.tag+"</span></div>";
var author = "<div class=\"blog-author\">Author: "+post.author+"</div>";
var date = "<div class=\"blog-date\">posted: "+formatDate(post.date)+"</div>";
var body = "<pre>"+post.body+"</pre>";
var program = "<div class=\"blog-program\">tag: "+post.program+"</div>";
var footer = "<hr style=\"border-top: 1px dotted #b0b0b0;border-bottom: 0px\">";
var entry = title+tag+author+date+body+program+footer;
```

is there a way to do it with bootstrap? or how would i go about doing this?

UPDATE and centered to the title

Comment: what do you mean by centered? vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to get Bootstrap involved here, just change the `blog-tag` element to a span and put it in the title div. Centering vertically can be hard in HTML, so I set the tag to be `position:relative` and moved it up 5px (`top:-5px;`).

**HTML**

```
<div> 
    <span class="blog-title">Jared Test 2</span> 
    <span class="blog-tag label label-warning ">Event</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.blog-tag {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rmhq8/6/)

To do this in javascript:

```
var titleAndTag = '<div><span class="blog-title" >'+post.title+'</span><span class="blog-tag label label-warning ">'+post.tag+'</span></div>';
```

Note that by using single quotes, you won't have to escape the double quotes.

Comment: sorry not the tag: ENG but the tag in JS which is the span label

Comment: Ah.. thanks, I just updated my answer and the link to the fiddle.

Comment: awesome, now how can i center it relative to the large title font

Comment: also it seems to inherit the blog-title characteristics. it makes the bootstrap label larger. i appreciate your help!

Comment: here is the following comparison. the bottom half is the size it should be. the top half is with the modifications. anyhelp would be appreciated. if not thats fine. you've already helped plenty